# Error logging / displaying in Silverlight WITHOUT developer SDK

Tags: c#, silverlight, logging

I've created a number of Silverlight applications used in various MS systems, from CRM 2011 to SharePoint.

The applications aren't perfect, and I'll be the first to admit it, and sometimes things go wrong. All my applications already display what went wrong:

```
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        (...)
            UIDispatcher.Invoke(() => ARP.DynamicsCRM2011.Silverlight.GlobalHelper.Controls.MessageWindow.ShowMessage(e.ExceptionObject.Message));
        (...)
    }
```

HOWEVER, almost always, the end user will NOT have the Silverlight developer SDK installed, and will, subsequently, only receive a generic *"Debugging Resource strings are unavailable"* message.

The message will usually contain some very basic form of the exception that occurred, but it's hardly ideal. I also know I'm missing a proper stack trace from the error (this is, of course, easy to fix).

I'm thinking of rewriting that exception handling code to show a generic "something went wrong, please try again message", and an extra "show log" button to display all the exception information along with the stack trace.

My question, however, is... how should I deal with those missing resource strings? If something goes wrong, I would like to get as much information as possible, but I cannot require my users to all install developer SDKs.

What's the best course of action in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is an option for you but you could log those info in database or in a local file that you could retrieve in case of error. But I don't kow if this is something you can consider (ex: application are for your compagnie but not public,etc.)

Comment: I've already modified my code to allow saving the exception (along with all inner exceptions) to disk... it's a bit lacking, as `Exception` cannot be easily serialized (Xml serialization cannot handle dictionaries, for example and `Exception` isn't properly marked for `DataContractSerializer`). The problem is, again, that the "message" part of the exception throws a meaningless *"Debugging Resource strings are unavailable"* message, rather than anything useful.

Comment: you could at least add the stacktrace so you would have an idea of where the error happend.

Comment: Also already implemented (albeit somewhat poorly, and I need to put some more work into it... when `Invoke(() => (...))` fails, then I get almost nothing in the stack trace.

Comment: While hardly ideal, this is the solution I ended up doing - i.e. saving the whole exception(s) with the stack trace for future analysis.